# How to send a value with a function within each function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the jQuery `each` function to call mouse events on hover:

```
$('.entry .post-entry a').each(function(){
    root.setDimensions(this);
    $(this).on("mouseenter", root.mouseEnter);
    $(this).on("mousemove", root.mouseMove);
    $(this).on("mouseleave", root.mouseLeave);
    $(this).on("click", root.onClick);
});
```

This works great, but I need to send the index of the item to these functions. The problem is, when I add the function marks: `()` at the end of each function, the function will be called after the page load, but I doesn't want this.

I know one method to send a variable to the function using parameters. But to use these, you should make use of the braces, like so:

```
$('.entry .post-entry a').each(function(index){
    var index = index;
    root.setDimensions(this);
    $(this).on("mouseenter", root.mouseEnter(index));
    $(this).on("mousemove", root.mouseMove(index));
    $(this).on("mouseleave", root.mouseLeave(index));
    $(this).on("click", root.onClick(index));
 });
```

How can I send a value without calling the function directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
$('.entry .post-entry a').each(function(index){
    var index = index;
    root.setDimensions(this);
    $(this).on("mouseenter", root.mouseEnter.bind(this, index));
    $(this).on("mousemove", root.mouseMove.bind(this, index));
    $(this).on("mouseleave", root.mouseLeave.bind(this, index));
    $(this).on("click", root.onClick.bind(this, index));
 });
```

With `bind()` you can bind(duh) a scope for the function(1st parameter) and then the parameters it will receive (2nd and forward param) when executed.

---

In fact what @RoryMcCrossan said is true: It isn't nice to bind events whitin a loop. The best practice is to bind them with one selection. *But*, he proposed to use `index()` inside the event, what can or cannot be a good ideia, depending on the frequency those events will be called. For that you can mix both methods, using `bind()` and `index()` togheter, but not repeating them:

```
$.fn.onWithIndex = function(eventType, callback) {
    $(this).on(eventType, function(e) {
    var $el = $(this),
            index = $el.data("index") ? $el.data("index") : $el.index();

    $el.data("index", index);
    callback.call(this, index, e);
  });
};

// Use
$(".posts a").onWithIndex("mouseenter", root.mouseEnter);
```

This function is a **sample** of how to do it. If you need those kind of events a lot, it could be a nice way to go. It run a event wrapper where it checks for a save index in the element's data, if not found, then it runs `index()`. Remeber that this function is a sample and does not work with the selector parameter like original `on()` does, e.g.: `$('...').on("mouseenter", "another-selector", function() { .. });` - that won't works.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/20uckbc4/)

Comment: And how should the function, like mouseEnter look like? Like so: `mouseEnter: function(event, index) {}`?

Comment: @Caspert no. The binded args will be placed first, so it will be `(index, event)`. When you don't know what arguments you have in a function, use `console.log(arguments)` to check them.

Comment: Okay, nice. So you can always use `console.log(arguments)` whatever parameter is send with the function? And maybe a stupid question, but do you prefer your methode or the one from @RoryMcCrossan?

Answer (score 1):

Create a bound function that will return a function with partially applied parameters.

```
$('.entry .post-entry a').each(function(index){
    var index = index;
    root.setDimensions(this);
    $(this).on("mouseenter", root.mouseEnter.bind(root, index));
    $(this).on("mousemove", root.mouseMove.bind(root, index));
    $(this).on("mouseleave", root.mouseLeave.bind(root, index));
    $(this).on("click", root.onClick.bind(root, index));
 });
```

Read more on the [`Function.prototype.bind` property here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the event handlers within the loop is redundant as each instance can get the current element index from the element which raised the event. Try this:

```
var $a = $('.entry .post-entry a');
$a.each(function() {
    root.setDimensions(this);
});

var root = {
    mouseEnter: function(e) {
        var index = $(this).index($a);
        // work with index here...
    },
    // other event handlers here...
}

$a.on({
    mouseenter: root.mouseEnter,
    mousemove: root.mouseMove,
    mouseleave: root.mouseLeave,
    click: root.onClick
});
```

Comment: That is a nice way for binding multiple events, but it isn't more expensive calling `index()` inside it any time ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown possibly, it would depend on how often the events are raised and what the OPs HTML structure looks like. You could keep the initial loop and set a `data` attribute on the `a` elements and store the index in there on load and just read it back within the event. The main thing I'm trying to avoid is creating event handlers in a loop :)

Comment: This 2nd option you proposed is probably the best.